# Open date setting in Kivy/Android app with jnius

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I'm trying to translate this Java code

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

to Kivy, so I can open the Android date settings dialog. So far, I tried with

```
from jnius import autoclass
from jnius import cast

from jnius import autoclass
from jnius import cast

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
intent = autoclass("android.provider.Settings")
currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
currentActivity.startActivity(intent.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS)
```

but I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 282, in read_queue
    ...
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 900, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__ (jnius/jnius.c:27749)
JavaException: No methods matching your arguments
```

I tried several alternatives with `setAction` and `setData` but none works so far

Comment: `autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')` is the first mistake, it should be `autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')`. I don't know how many other issues there are though.